# Detect if file contains image data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have an excel file changed its extension to jpg.
tried uploading that file as an image 
having filter "image/*" still that file is accepted because of file.type in image/jpg

Any way I can detect file is not an image?
I am using ng-file-upload

Comment: do you have `ngf-pattern="'image/*'"` or `ngf-accept="'image/*'"`?

Comment: yes added both of them, 
 I don't think i can trust the content/meta type